# Bootstrap table color to print

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, printing

I made a bootstrap table where I get information to fill up from a stored procedure with some indication where some text are in color or even background.

The trouble is when I want to print, there isn't any color. I can make a file `print.css` where I'll tell the background color for header and title, but how about the table when i don't even know what will be inside depending of the stored procedure? And more, the table isn't separated well between each pages where it cut my table or words.

This is what I've done until now from my page `print.css` where I use already td or th for the table :

```
.table tr {
    page-break-after: always;
} 

@media print {
    @page {
        size: letter;
        margin: 1cm;
    }
}

body{
  -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
}

.panel-heading {
    background-color: #54A0EB !important;
}

.panel-title {
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

@media print {
    .table td,
    .table th {
            background-color: inherit !important;
    }

    .table-stripe {
            background-color: #dedede !important;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Does i need to use visible-print class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My css bootstrap was double that's why i can't see color. Everything is fine now.